# Django-Storages S3 with minio as backend

Tags: python, django, python-django-storages

i would like to use django-storages with minio so i tryd to adopt settings, configs etc. I found on the web but for some reason my access key or the way it gets provided fails with the following error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidAccessKeyId) when calling the PutObject operation: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.
```

if i run `manage.py collectstatic`

settings.py

```
#S3 config
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'MyProject/static'),
]
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '9VOWWCTSMX4ZEGVW7N9D'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'zJFf9BYWk0TM3FVwyY98UFy0o+DQF0oY1vCXgLqV'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'static'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '127.0.0.1:9000'

AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
    'CacheControl': 'max-age=86400',
}

AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATIC_URL = 'http://%s/%s/' % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, AWS_LOCATION)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

Is there maybe someone that has already done this?

Comment: Can you add the doc/package link that you are using?

Answer (score 14):

Here is what I did to get it to work

```py
# settings.py

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'static'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = minio_access_key
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = minio_secret_key
AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL = minio_address (eg. http://localhost:9000)
```

Versions:

- boto3==1.10.45
- Django==3.0.1
- django-storages==1.8
- Minio==2019-12-26T01:55:09Z (Docker image built from the source code to run on RPi4)

**Note:** versions were latest when installed using `pip install <package>`

I didn't attempt to use `django-minio-storage` since it does not support Django3.

If you have upgraded your package versions, try what I did. If not try setting `S3_HOST  = '127.0.0.1:9000'` .

`AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL` from [django-storage docs](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#settings)

> `AWS_S3_ENDPOINT_URL` (optional: default is None, **boto3 only**)
>      Custom S3 URL to use when connecting to S3, including scheme. Overrides `AWS_S3_REGION_NAME` and `AWS_S3_USE_SSL` . To avoid AuthorizationQueryParametersError error, `AWS_S3_REGION_NAME` should also be set.

**Troubleshooting**
Disconnect from the internet and run `manage.py collectstatic` to see the address to which boto fails to connect.